# How to unlock phone using DevicePolicyManager

Tags: android, device-admin

I know how to lock device using DevicePolicyManager..

```
boolean active = mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdminSample);
            if (active) mDPM.lockNow();
```

but how to undo this(unlock a phone)?

Comment: i doubt, we cant unlock password protected phone programatically.

Comment: @Stacks28 If phone is not password protected then is it possible ?

Comment: may be look this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
KeyguardManager mKeyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager) DetSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mLock = mKeyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock("MainActivity");
                mLock.disableKeyguard();
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html#UnlockDevice

However, I am not satisfy myself with this solution as it uses deprecated methods... hope that someone knows more...